# Archive field in packages menu buffer

Tags: package

I'd like to remove the **Archive** field column that appears in my **packages menu buffer**, but haven't been able to find a setting to allow me to do this.  I've tried all I can find in the `m-x packages-menu-` group but drawn a blank.  As the fm is immense, I wonder if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The packages menu uses a derived version of tabulated-list-mode in order to display the packages.  The columns are set in such a way that if you're using multiple archives (i.e. melpa and elpa), then it defines that column.  There doesn't appear to be any non-hacky way of removing it.

There are two changes I made in package.el:

In the call to `define-derived-mode package-menu-mode`, this needs to be removed:

```
,@(if (cdr package-archives)
      '(("Archive" 10 package-menu--archive-predicate)))
```

and this from `package-menu--print-info`:

```
,@(if (cdr package-archives)
      (list (propertize (or (package-desc-archive pkg-desc) "")
                        'font-lock-face face)))
```

This is in Emacs 24.5.1.

You can redefine those functions after including 'package in your init file, or maybe you can use defadvice or something.  I redefined them in the scratch buffer and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Very helpful.  I've been able to find a **package.elc** in `/usr/share/emacs/` and I also found an archived **package.el** which I extracted, edited as you suggested and placed in `~/.emacs.d/`    Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have done the trick.  I'm obviously missing something that would be very obvious to somebody who better understands emacs' lisp behaviour.  Where should I be looking?

Comment: The easiest way would be to take those edited functions and put them directly in your init.el after `(require 'package)`.

Comment: Great!  That worked.  And more important, I've learned from you that I can override any function definition by including it in init.el.  Thanks for taking the time.